# Need help in identifying and fixing SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to do a post to TLS server for both default and custom keystores. After obtaining CloseableHttpClient instance when I do an execute

```
CloseableHttpResponse response1 = client.execute(postMethod);
```

This is giving me `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <hostname.domain.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []` exception on above line.

Below is a class where I prepare client instance

```
public class ClientelUtil {

    public static CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient(String scheme,SSLContext sslContext) {
        HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();
        CloseableHttpClient client = null;
        if ("https".equalsIgnoreCase(scheme)) {
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
            final Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                    .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory()).register("https", sFactory).build();

            final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);

            clientBuilder = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sFactory)
                    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                    .setConnectionManager(cm);
        }
        client = clientBuilder.build();
        return client;

    }

    public static CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient(String scheme) {
        return getHttpClient(scheme, getSSLContext());

    }

    public static CloseableHttpClient getHttpClientWithoutTLSValidation(String scheme) {
        return getHttpClient(scheme, getSSLContextWithoutValidation());

    }

    public static SSLContext getSSLContextWithoutValidation() {
        SSLContext sslContext=null;
        try {
            sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {
                public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
                    return true;
                }
            }).build();
        } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sslContext;
    }

    public static SSLContext getSSLContext() {
        SSLContext sslContext=null;
        try {
            JKSInfo jksInfo = JKSUtil.getTrustStoreInfo();
            sslContext = HttpSSLUtil.getSSLContext(jksInfo.getJksPath(), jksInfo.getJksPassword());
        } catch (HttpSSLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sslContext;
    }

}
```

Here is where I am using above class in my program

```
public String post(String host,int port,Map<String,String> data) {

    CloseableHttpClient client = null;
    String response = null;
    String protocol = HTTP;
    try{
        if( isServerSSLEnabled() ){ //returns a boolean tru or false. In this case it is true
            protocol = HTTPS;
        }
        client = ClientelUtil.getHttpClient(protocol);
        //RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setCircularRedirectsAllowed(true).build();
        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder()
                    .setScheme(protocol)
                    .setHost(host).setPort(port)
                    .setPath(CONNECT_URI);

        URI uri = builder.build();

        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(uri);
        //postMethod.setConfig(requestConfig);
        logger.debug("Sending request on host [" + host +"], port ["+ port+"], Protocol ["+ protocol + "] connectURI ["+CONNECT_URI+"]");


        addRequestHeaders(postMethod);
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        try {
            for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : data.entrySet()) {
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()));
            }
            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
            CloseableHttpResponse response1 = client.execute(postMethod);       // <-- SSLPeerUnverifiedException at this point
            response = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error while running the scenario on node host [" + host+"]",e);
        } finally{
            postMethod.releaseConnection();
        }
    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(client!=null)
            try {
                client.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    return response;
}
```

I am using apache http client 4.5 for this, please help on identifying what is wrong here.

Also is `CN=FQDN` required in keystore used in `getSSLContext` method as I am using `NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE` to create `HttpClientBuilder`?

Thanks

**Update**

I created a new truststore file with `Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:` as my hostname, after which above code is working (Now I am using **hostname** to access my server code instead of **hostname.domain.com** as mentioned above in my question).

Now my question is, in case where `CN` | `Common Name` is not present in truststore file can it be verified using some modification in above code? Please suggest. Thanks again.

**Update**

Posting full stack trace. Also is it a good practice to return true in case of hostname verifier so that it ignores hostname verification and works incase of no CN or SAN is provided in production (Please let me know when this can be used and otherwise)?

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <hostname.domain.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:467)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:397)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at com.code.app.myapp.utils.HttpUtil.post(HttpUtil.java:102)
    at com.code.app.myapp2.RequestDispatcher.dispatchRequest(RequestDispatcher.java:61)
    at com.code.app.chain.commands.FetchDiagnosticsInfo.executeOperation(FetchDiagnosticsInfo.java:82)
    at com.informatica.tools.ui.isomorphic.DSCommand.execute(DSCommand.java:45)
    at com.code.app.chain.commands.BaseDSCommand.execute(BaseDSCommand.java:59)
    at com.informatica.tools.ui.isomorphic.RPCCommand.execute(RPCCommand.java:43)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:166)
    at com.informatica.tools.ui.isomorphic.RPCController.execute(RPCController.java:97)
    at com.code.app.ui.IsomorphicController.execute(IsomorphicController.java:115)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:166)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ExecuteCommand.execute(ExecuteCommand.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:166)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:175)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:166)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.code.app.ui.security.UserIdentifierFilter.doFilter(UserIdentifierFilter.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.code.app.ui.i18n.InfEncodingFilter.doFilter(InfEncodingFilter.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.code.app.config.InfSessionTimeoutManagerFilter.doFilter(InfSessionTimeoutManagerFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.code.app.ui.security.ResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeaderFilter.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: This is a problem with the server certificate, or the DNS mapping, not your code.

Comment: @EJP: Thanks, also is `CN=FQDN` required in keystore used in getSSLContext method as I am using `NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE` to create HttpClientBuilder?

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace in your question.

Comment: @EJP: I have added full stack trace. `post` method is from `com.code.app.myapp.utils.HttpUtil` class

Comment: What's the server cert look like? Has it got the correct CN or alternative names? What do you get if you run `true | openssl s_client -connect hostname.domain.com:443 | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep -E "(Subject|DNS):"`

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the server you are trying to access has a valid certificate? or you do not have a secure certificate but is just trying to figure out how to successfully call without having those issues? This is critical because for development you can bypass it, but it is not recommended for production. You must have a valid and secure certificate to your server to solve that problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with the server certificate, or the DNS mapping, not your code. The server name you connected to is not present in the SSL certificate it presented.

You should not look for insecure workarounds like null HTTPS hostname verifiers.

Comment: "You should not look for insecure workarounds like null HTTPS hostname verifiers." By this do you mean returning true while verifying hostnames `HttpClientBuilder.setHostnameVerifier`? If yes please explain why shouldn't it be used? Thanks

Comment: *Because it's an insecure workaround.* You need to find and fix the *problem.* If you don't want it secure, why use HTTPS at all?

Comment: the problem with this and all these "you can't use insecure SSL" perfect-world, perfectly unhelpful answers is because sometimes you don't have any control over what the remote system is giving you. The remote system's SSL is insecurely configured and *I can't do anything about it*. But I still need to talk to it. Sure, they should simply have just exposed this internal, local-network API as HTTP, but they didn't, they self-signed, and now we have to deal with it somehow.

Comment: @DoctorEval The trouble with insecure SSL is that it is a contradiction in terms. If you don't need it secure, why use SSL at all? But if it's just a matter of a self-signed certficate, the secure solution is simple: import it into the truststore. Rather than trusting every certificate from everywhere, or bypassing any other security mechanism.